# Elements not included in div when added using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a list of products on my website a Catalogue. The following PHP Code uses javascript to create a div and insert all the product description links inside it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Products ORDER BY `Name` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "<script>document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = '<div class=ks>';</script>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rowid = $row['Id'];
    $xx = '<a href="Getdesc.php?hid='.$rowid . '" class=lnk>' . $row['Name'] . '</a><br>';
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('products').innerHTML += '$xx';</script>";
}
echo "<script>document.getElementById('products').innerHTML += '</div>';</script>";
```

Ignore all the `ks` style sheet class and all the mysql stuff for now.
The problem is it displays the grey backgrounded div (grey from style sheet)
and THEN the links. I need the links to be inside the div.
For a little explanation for those of you who are confused by the pieces of code unrelated to the primary purpose of this question,

1. The Products table in MySQL is a table that hold all my product info including price, name, id, e.t.c.
2. the `"Getdesc.php?hid=..."` link is a link to a php web page that will display all the information about the product from it's Id.
3. "Products" is an Id of a different div that contains this internal div (With the products I mean) PLUS some other stuff ( I don't feel like telling you all about it).

Sorry for the messy code, thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't an answer but theres a few things to note for future: it would be smart to seperate javascript from php, and not to use `*` for SELECT queries. 

You are also doing lookups for elements every time which is a bit inefficient..specially if have a lot of rows to loop...

Comment: why not just have the php script output the html directly then use an ajax request to load that php script and append the html on success?

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the advice!, I will try to do it that way instead

Comment: Would it be a good solution to add a seperate javascript function that takes an Array of Product names and destination links and puts it in the div, and then call it from PHP when the MySQL Query is finished?

Comment: The most ideal option is to `json_encode` the query results and send it to the client using javascript ajax requests. Then you can use a JS function to `json parse` the data and append to a div with a loop :)

Comment: One thing I don't understand... Why should my question be down-voted? what did I do wrong?

Comment: @user2332868 get used to it. Stack overflow is full of trolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not put everything in a variable :

```
$html = '<div class="ks">'; // btw you forgot those double-quotes. you html won't evaluate the class if not surrounded by double-quotes
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $rowid = $row['Id'];
    $xx = '<a href="Getdesc.php?hid='.$rowid . '" class=lnk>' . $row['Name'] . '</a><br>';
    $html.= $xx;
}
$html.= '</div>';
```

then echo it? if you're using php, then there's no need to change the page with javascript after it's been loaded, you just sent all the remainder of the page to the client, why not directly put this code at the right place?

```
echo $html;
```

Comment: How would he append the contents to div id `products` from that code? some form of javascript would be required, it would be assumed hes trying to add the contents after the document has already loaded...

Comment: say the page just been loaded. It came from this particular php script. the page being echoed comes from the script. just move the lines to where you build the page, with everything else, namely the product div. unless he wishes to use AJAX but doesn't know it yet :p

Comment: How was I so dumb not to note that possibility??? :-(. Thank you, by the way I can put the php straight into the "Products", so that works for me. also somehow my HTML code worked without the double-quotes around "ks"

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier fair point, not the cleanest solution but it works :P

Comment: I don't particularly like AJAX... I try to avoid it... Maybe cos I'm not too good at JS anyway :-(.

Comment: What don't you like about it... when you know how to use it properly it makes your site much cleaner to handle, plus its good practice imo to seperate client code from  server code, although there are some exceptions to that ! :)

Comment: Ok, I will start using it but It will be a pain

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript:**

```
//from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
function reqListener () {
  document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = this.responseText;
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.php", true);
oReq.send();
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT <columns> from Products ORDER BY `Name` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo '<div class="ks">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rowid = $row['Id'];
  echo '<a href="Getdesc.php?hid=' . $rowid . '" class="lnk">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Name']) . '</a><br>';
}
echo '</div>'
```